# BB 1.1.2 + lodash + requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, lodash

How to implement lodash with new version of BB 1.1.1 or 1.1.2, which has AMD wrapper?
And how to exports Backbone into global scope, with requirejs?

1.1.0 - without amd wrapper, works good.
Thnk's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this in your config should work:

```
paths: {
    underscore: <path to lodash>,
    backbone: <path to backbone>,
    jquery: <path to jquery>
}
```

You must use a version of lodash that is compatible with Backbone. This is the one created with `lodash backbone` when you use the CLI. You do not need shims of any of these. Defining `underscore` so that it points to lodash will make Backbone use lodash.

Comment: I would add that I learned the hard way that everything that wants Lodash/Underscore in your project should require "underscore". It does not seem tot work to define both "underscore" and "lodash" and point them to the same path.

Comment: @acjay I found that out the hard way, too. I added an answer to address that situation.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the version created with `lodash backbone`. That would be the version with the minimum API that supports backbone, a subset of the modern version, right?

Comment: @webXL I guess you could get by with the `lodash underscore` build, but I would not advise using anything else than this build or `lodash backbone`. The best description of the differences is [here](http://kitcambridge.be/blog/custom-builds-in-lo-dash-2-dot-0/): "[the backbone and underscore builds] include performance improvements and limited consistency fixes; however, for **maximum compatibility, some optimizations and fixes have been removed.**" I'd be concerned about getting difficult-to-fix bugs if I went with another build.

Comment: @Louis Thanks. I took a look at the client and I see A LOT of underscore compatibility checks that get invoked if the `backbone` modifier is requested. I wonder how much of that is to be compatible with older versions of backbone vs. just the way backbone is written.

Answer (score 10):

If you have libraries that depend on lodash explicitly, such as [lodash-template-loader](https://github.com/tbranyen/lodash-template-loader), you will need to use this:

```
paths: {
    lodash: <path to lodash>,
    ....
},
map: {
  "*": {
    "underscore": "lodash"
  }
}
```

At that point, any dependency on underscore will load lodash instead, and the template loader will work.